# Wordpress: Hook the post update button or form for validation

Tags: jquery, wordpress, button

I want to cancel the post update in some circunstances **without the need to reload** the entire page.

I've tried:

```
// publish is the id of the Update button.
$('#publish').click(function(){
    return false;
});

// post is the id of the corresponding form.
$('#post').submit(function(){
     return false;
});
```

In both codes the form it's not submitted but the Update button remain disabled and the ajax loader gif is showed.

How I can do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, with the help of those who answered my question (specially to **stealthyninja**), I managed to bring working what I asked.

**@karevn**: This solution doesn't break the **autosave** in current WordPress version (tested up to 3.2.1).

```
$('#publish').click(function(e) {
    if (!condition) {

        // Fix WordPress display to user.
        $('#ajax-loading').hide();
        $('#publish').removeClass('button-primary-disabled');               

        return false;
    }     
});
```

Comment: Yes, it does not. But the validation will not be run if I will submit the form by pressing Enter key or using some other way. So you need to handle "submit". I tried to add my handler there and that broke autosave in my case.

Answer (score 1):

I think because WordPress already has an event handler on that element it doesn't matter what it returns, it's just firing both even handlers. Try this:

```
$('#publish').click(function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: __@Rusty Jeans:__ Thanks for the answer but that don't worked for me. I tried also with return false in the click handler body without any result.

Answer (score 1):

Did you also try:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#post').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $('.ajax-loading').hide();
        $('#publish').removeAttr("disabled"); 
    });
});
```

Comment: With `e.preventDefault();` stop the submitting but it keeps showing the ajax loader and the Update button remains disabled too.

Comment: @diosney: See update -- it should hide the Ajax loader and re-enable the update button for you.

Comment: __@stealthyninja__: That didn't worked but provided me more testing examples that help a lot to find the way to do what I needed. Thanks for the help +1 for it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it is impossible - it breaks autosave in current WordPress version. You can submit a patch to WP or stick to another solution.

Comment: __@karevn__: Are you sure? There is no hack in jQuery that can do the trick?